# BlueZ over DBus stops responding within varying intervals

Tags: c++, ubuntu, bluez, gio

I am currently using the BlueZ DBus API to scan for BLE devices but it stops responding completely after varying intervals. Sometimes it's minutes, other times it's one or two hours.

My assumption is that I am forgetting to do something. The strange thing is, that after I exit the application, tools like `bluetoothctl` and `hciconfig` also no longer respond. Sometimes a reboot is not enough to get it to work again and I need to power-cycle the machines. It happens on several different machines as well.

I am acquiring the bus using:

```
GError* error = nullptr;
mConnection = g_bus_get_sync(G_BUS_TYPE_SYSTEM, nullptr, &error);
```

Starting the loop:

```
mLoop = g_main_loop_new(nullptr, false);
g_main_loop_run(mLoop);
```

Then I power on the adapter by setting the `Powered` property to true and calling `StartDiscovery`. Devices are then reported through:

```
guint iface_add_sub = g_dbus_connection_signal_subscribe(mConnection, "org.bluez", "org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager", "InterfacesAdded", nullptr, nullptr, G_DBUS_SIGNAL_FLAGS_NONE, device_appeared, this, nullptr);

guint iface_remove_sub
        = g_dbus_connection_signal_subscribe(mConnection, "org.bluez", "org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager", "InterfacesRemoved", nullptr, nullptr, G_DBUS_SIGNAL_FLAGS_NONE, device_disappeared, this, nullptr);
```

Is there anything I am missing to prevent BlueZ from stopping to respond?

- bluetoothd -v = 5.53
- ldd --version = GLIBC 2.31-0ubuntu9.2

Comment: I would try attaching a debugger to bluetoothd while it's stuck. Not guaranteed to yield useful information, but it might! (this is why open source is great)

Comment: It appears there is not a lot of information from the logs at least (after adding -d). It just stops logging without any visible error.

Comment: a debugger means gdb

Answer (score 1):

Bluez cannot scan indefinitely because it will crash, as you are observing. In my opinion it is a bug…

What I do is to scan for 8 seconds and then stop the scan. Bluez will then clean up internal cache. After allowing 1 second for cleanup, I restart the scan.

This way it will hold up much longer. Nonetheless after a week or so it might still crash…

Comment: I was afraid of this answer as I heard some of it through the grapevine. I have tried implementing this by calling StopDiscovery and StartDiscovery at your suggested interval but it still appears to stop working. Do you completely close the DBus connection as well when restarting the scan or do something in addition to stop/start?

Comment: Did it not make any difference? I don't close the dbus connection.  You can file a bug on the Bluez repo on Github…